# Pattern for Managing States in React Native Project for Efficiency and 95% cleaner code

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-context

Well its more of like **Choose Redux or not** type of Question so bear with me.

**How can we have React Native apps working with all good flows and 95% cleaner code!**

> here are my suggestion

**Using way one**

> (out of the box with raw code)

- React native init project
- Custom architecture by separating components and everything in their specific folder
- Managing each components state in the file
- Managing reusable components using props
- Passing states data using react navigation params

**Using way two**

> (popular old school)

- React native init project
- Use Redux subs and reduce pattern
- StoryBook for managing isolation based component testing

**Using way three**

> (popular and latest standard)

- React native init project
- Use Context Api pattern
- Use React hooks for state managing
- StoryBook for managing isolation based component

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @iuliu.net .  How can we have React Native apps working with all good flows and 95% cleaner code?

Comment: I would like to go the third approach, it's new and clean